# How to fix urls in Yii2 on live server?

Tags: url, routes, controller, yii2, http-status-code-404

I have live server on apache.
And it should be working when I go to the site [www.example.com/sitename](http://www.example.com/sitename).
When I go to [www.example.com/sitename/web](http://www.example.com/sitename/web) only the home page works.

To create links I use:

```
<?= Html::a('logowanie', '/site/login'); ?>
```

But there is problem with go to controller because link refers to [www.example.com/site/login](http://www.example.com/site/login) and this not working. 'sitename' is missing. It shows: 404 Not Found.
On localhost everything worked fine. Any ideas how to fix it?

My .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

# Change default directory page
# DirectoryIndex web/index.php

# Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

config:

```
   $config = [
        'id' => 'basic',
        'name' => 'kolos',
        'language' => 'pl',
        'homeUrl' => '/',
        'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
        'components' => [
            'urlManager' => [
                'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                'showScriptName' => false,
                'rules' => [
                ],
            ],
    'modules' => [
        'user' => [
            'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
        ],
    ],
```

I'm using to login https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate URL using `UrlManager`, you need to pass it as array to indicate that this is route and it should be processed.

```php
<?= Html::a('logowanie', ['/site/login']) ?>
```

`'/site/login'` means literally `/site/login` URL, Yii won't change it in any way, so it will never include a subdirectory.